# how to get column value on onEditingStart: function(e)

Tags: jquery, devexpress, devextreme

```js
function mydata() {
  function logEvent(eventName) {
    var el = $("#eventContainer .eventLog"),
      value = el.text();
    value += ((value && ", ") + eventName);
    el.text(value);
  }

  function update(id) {
    alert(id);
  }
  datagrid = $("#gridContainer").dxDataGrid({ // this is my code for datagrid

    editing: {
      mode: "row",
      allowUpdating: true,
      allowDeleting: true,
      allowAdding: true
    },
    columns: [{
        dataField: "ORDER_ID",
        caption: "ORDER_ID",
        sortOrder: 'desc',
        fixed: true
      }, {
        dataField: "INV_NAME",
        caption: "INV_NAME"

      }, {
        dataField: "ID",
        caption: "ID",
        fixed: true

      }


    ]
    onEditingStart: function(e) {
      btnid = cellInfo.data.ORDER_ID + "_" + cellInfo.data.ID;

      update(btnid);
      logEvent("EditingStart");

    }
  });
}
```

on click on Edit  button value in btnid  variable(global variable) should pass in update() function sholud alert the value(but this is not working ) i am using default devexpress edit mode  link button i want  ORDER_ID and ID to store in variable and then alert in update() function using default devexpress edit mode  link button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onEditingStart: function(e) {
  btnid = e.data.ORDER_ID + "_" + e.data.ID;
  update(btnid);
  logEvent("EditingStart");

}
```